# CSS: text content on scroll does not show 100% of viewport

Tags: html, css, layout, viewport

I'm smashing my head against the wall with this problem. I think its related with CSS basic layout but I'm not seeing it... therefore I ask for help of other professionals so you can help me. Check the following link:

http://rosasusaeta.com/cepods/how-we-work.php

If you scroll below to the bottom you will observe that the whole content is not displayed, as if it was a bit beneath the viewport. To see what I mean, select the text towards the bottom and then the scroll does work.

I tried to apply a margin-bottom to the content `.content-block` but it didn't make any effect until more or less 200px, which makes no sense. Could somebody maybe help me out?

Comment: Obviously the problem with your styles. put up some code. you might have set overflow hidden on the parent and set the divs height to a value larger than the remaining height of the veiwport.

Comment: I see the problem. It is because you have the height set to 100%, then it doesn't touch at the top of the screen so the content is then pushed the same distance below the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Set the height of '.content-block' to 80%. It will work fine.

The problem is you set the height of the content-block to 100% and body overflow to hidden.
So the portion of the content-block below viewport will not be visible.

Comment: It works but this would be an issue depending on screen resolution no?

Comment: Yea ofcourse, the problem is that you are fixing the height of the footer in pixel. It won't resize according to window resolution. Either you set the height everything in percentage. Or go for a wild "css media query" attempt.

Comment: There is another way. Ill get back in few minutes. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a kind of fix. I really don't feel happy using this as a solution, I would like to learn to do a better layout and learn what I could do for the next time but for now. I used this solution:

I applied the css below to .main-content. Therefore it substracts 155px from the total height.
The 155px are the height of the trapezium in the footer, the height of the header of the main block and the margin of the main block.

```
height: calc(100% - 155px);
```

I had no idea if the existence of `calc()` but it seems very useful. My site needs to be optimized only for desktops so I have no problem but this is not a overall solution as the mobile browsers will not work correctly:

http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

```
        html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
        .page .header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 5%;
            background-color: #0094ff;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

.page .body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px; // same as the footer height
}

.page .body .content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}    

.page .footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

// markup

```
<body class="page">  // add class page to body

    <section class="header">
        <div class="full-height as-inline-block">
            Header
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="body">
        <div class="content">
            Page body
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="footer">
        footer
    </section>


</body>
```

Comment: This fill enable your site to adapt to window resolution. This can be used as the layout for all pages. Put your content inside '.content'. You are done.

Comment: I see you have used position fixed several times. I thought position: fixed should be avoided.

Comment: You are fixing elements in the layout. It wouldn't have been be there if it was not supposed to use.

Comment: This layout is resizable to an extent. But you need to combine it with css media queries to set the font-sizes to get a completely resizable site. On resize the font-sizes should adjust itself to fit inside the containers.

Comment: I will try your solution as calc() does not work with chrome or Safari on IOS and that can be a great issue.